# How to implement multicolored flashing sprite effect like in Contra and the Messenger?

Tags: 2d, shaders, glsl, fragment-shader, graphic-effects

I want to implement an effect similar to what you see in this [clip](https://youtu.be/iooQeqdyB8E?t=2942) of Contra.

When the boss takes damage, he flashes wildly with different colors.

A similar effect can be seen in this [clip](https://youtu.be/u7uSq1KghpE?t=249) from the Messenger (with the addition of an outline).

I don't care how they did it in Contra or the Messenger. I want to achieve a similar effect, preferably with a shader using GLSL.

**Any ideas on how to go about it?**

The effect seems to alternate the sprites between red and blue palettes, but I'm not sure if palette swapping is an effective way to achieve this, especially since I don't have my art assets in gray scale.

Maybe a hue shift shader is a viable alternative? Or maybe there's another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could achieve this effect by using a rotating color palette. You can do this in GLSL by passing in a grayscale image and a 1D texture containing the color palette. You'd sample the grayscale image and use the resulting value to lookup into the 1D texture. You get the palette rotation by adding a value to the grayscale value. Something like this (not tested, probably has mistakes):

```
uniform sampler2D image;
uniform sampler1D colorPalette;
uniform float offset; // <- value between 0 and 1 that increases on each frame and wraps around
void main()
{
    float grayscalePixel = texture2D(gl_TexCoord[0], image);
    float paletteLookup = fract(grayscalePixel + offset);
    return texture1D(paletteLookup, colorPalette);
}
```